# How to create diagonal of table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create diagonal in my table. For example if i have table 5x5 i have to grab first row and first column in this row and set background of thic column to be red. For the second row i have to do the same on second column in second row.

```js
var cols = 6,
  rows = 6;

for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>')
  $('table').append(row);

  for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    var col = $('<td></td>');
    row.append(col);
    $(col[r][c]).addClass('kolorek')
  }
}
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.kolorek {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

</table>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marko90/027r32yn/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.

```js
var cols = 6,
 rows = 6,
    $table = $('table'); // Caching the table, because this will be called many times (perf improvement)
    
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
     var row = $('<tr></tr>')
     
      for(c = 0; c < cols; c++){
       var col = $('<td></td>')
        if(c==r) col.addClass('kolorek') // col[r][c] is undefined. This matches the same column and row numbers
        row.append(col)
      }
      $table.append(row);
    }
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.kolorek {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the row index equals the column index to make a diagonal line from left top to right bottom:

```js
var cols = 6,
  rows = 6;

for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>')
  $('table').append(row);

  for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
    var col = $('<td></td>');
    row.append(col);

    if (r == c) col.addClass('kolorek'); // add this in place of your current kolerik adder
  }
}
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.kolorek {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

</table>
```

Comment: Damn, same answer at the same time. You got the prime.